# For Azure Data Factories is there a way to 'Validate all' using powershell rather than the GUI?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

- A working Azure Data Factory (ADF) exists that contains pipelines with activities that are dependent on database tables
- The definition of a database table changes
- The next time the pipeline runs it fails
- Of course we can set up something so it fails gracefully but ...
- I need to proactively execute a scheduled Powershell script that iterates through all ADFs (iterating is easy) to do the equivalent of the 'Validate All' (validating is impossible?) functionality that the GUI provides
- I do realise that the Utopian CI/CD DevOps environment I dream about will one day in the next year or so achieve this via other ways
- I need the automation validation method today - not in a year!

I've looked at what I think are all of the powershell cmdlets available and short of somehow deleting and redeploying each ADF (fraught with danger) I can't find a simple method to validate an Azure Data Factory via Powershell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the ".Net" SDK, each of the models has a "Validate()" method.  I have not yet found anything similar in the Powershell commands.
In my experience, the (GUI) validation is not foolproof.  Some things are only tested at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while and you said you didn't want the validation to work in an year - but after a couple of years we finally have both the Validate all and Export ARM template features from the Data Factory user experience via a publicly available npm package [@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities). The full guidance can be found on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements).